# Difference in POST request data received by Flask server when called from urllib and Postman

Tags: python, flask, httprequest, postman, urllib

The flask server just prints the data that it receives from a client making a POST request. It also checks for the *presence* of **Authorization** header.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/random', methods=['POST'])
def random():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.headers.get('Authorization') and request.headers.get('Content-Type') == 'application/json':
            print(request.get_json())
            print(request.data)
            return "Success"
        else:
            print(request.get_json())
            print(request.data)
            return "Bad request"

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Now when I test the API from **Postman** it works perfectly. However we are going to test it slightly differently. In your headers **un-check** both the **Authorization** and **Content-Type** header and then in the body send this json-

```
{"spam": 1, "eggs": 2, "bacon": 0}
```

The output on the terminal is -

```
None
b'{"spam": 1, "eggs": 2, "bacon": 0}'
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2018 12:25:33] "?[37mPOST /random HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
```

Now, we will do the same thing via `urllib`. Following is the code for that-

```
import json
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
d = {"spam": 1, "eggs": 2, "bacon": 0}
data = json.dumps(d)
data = data.encode()
req = urllib.request.Request("http://localhost:5000/random", data)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
req.add_header('Authorization', 12345)

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Which works perfectly. However to recreate what we did with Postman we will comment out the `req.add_header` lines as follows -

```
#req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
#req.add_header('Authorization', 12345)
```

And then when we execute the script we get this output from it -

```
None
b''
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2018 12:27:18] "?[37mPOST /random HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
```

I need to know which of the two is the correct **expected behavior** and why are these two differing ?